# findContours error 'support only 8uC1 images'

Tags: image-processing, opencv

Trying to run findContours on a binary image"

```
Mat conv(image.size(), CV_8U);
image.convertTo(conv, CV_8U);
vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;

findContours(conv, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

thorws error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats ([Start]FindContours support only 8uC1 images) in cvStartFindContours,
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.3rc/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=convertto#void%20Mat::convertTo%28OutputArray%20m,%20int%20rtype,%20double%20alpha,%20double%20beta%29%20const):

> C++: void Mat::convertTo(OutputArray m, int rtype, double alpha=1, double beta=0 ) const
> Parameters:
>
> **rtype** – desired output matrix type or, rather, the depth since the number of
> channels are the same as the input has; if rtype is negative, the output matrix will have the same type as the input.

You see that the number of channels is not changed by `convertTo`, this means most probably that you get 3 channels (r, g and b). However `findContours` requires a monochrome image.

You need to convert the image to black-and-white:

```
cv::Mat bwImage;
cv::cvtColor(image, bwImage, CV_RGB2GRAY);
vector< vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(bwImage, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: Is there a way I can reduce it to monochrome? I already have a black and white image which was filtered with canny from another program

Comment: @0xSina: yes, just added it :)